# how to add Positioned stack inside SliverList and make it scrollable , like when we scroll the top image part will hide and only see appBar&scroll

Tags: flutter, stack, overlapping, scrollable, sliverappbar

[here i am pasting the video link i want to achieve , please help](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/_GHl4uF7xXE)hi here i want to add a container at the top of the scrollable side and also some part of the container should be at the end of app bar and it should be scrollable

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            leading:IconButton(onPressed: (){},
              icon:const Icon(Icons.arrow_back) ,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            actions: [
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: IconButton(onPressed: (){},
                  icon:const Icon(Icons.notifications_none_outlined) ,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: IconButton(onPressed: (){},
                  icon:const Icon(Icons.more_vert_outlined) ,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ],
            backgroundColor: ThemeManager.sliverAppBarColor,
            expandedHeight: 350.0,
            pinned: true,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              background: Padding(
                padding:  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(height: 60,),
                    ClipOval(
                      child: Container(
                        child: Image.asset(
                          '',
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          width: 120,
                          height: 120,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const Text('',
                    style: TextStyle(color: ThemeManager.profileNameTextColor,
                      fontSize: 24,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    ),),
                    const Center(
                      child: Text('',
                        style: TextStyle(color:
                        ThemeManager.profileNameTextColor,
                          fontSize: 16,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        ),

                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 3,),
                    // const EmployeeIdContainer(),
                    const SizedBox(height: 8,),
                    const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                    const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                  (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Stack(
                      children: [
                        Positioned(
                          top:-10,
                          left: 0,
                          right: 0,
                          bottom: 0,
                          child: Container(
                            width: 400,
                            height: 500,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
              },
              childCount: 50, // Number of list items
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here i want to acheive is when we scroll the appbar the scollable container top end must be in FlexibleSpaceBar means the container should be stacked in top -10 position.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate` and little math for visualization.

```dart
final double bottom = lerpDouble(-100, 10, shrinkOffset / expandedHeight)!;
```

Here is the snippet

```dart
class AppSliverPersistentHeaderDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  AppSliverPersistentHeaderDelegate({
    required this.expandedHeight,
  });

  final double expandedHeight;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    final double bottom = lerpDouble(-100, 10, shrinkOffset / expandedHeight)!; // play with your values here
    return ColoredBox(
      // you may use ImageFilter instead
      color: Colors.red.withOpacity(.1),
      child: Stack(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        children: [
          Positioned(
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: bottom,
            child: Placeholder(
              //replace with image and increase height>maxExtent
              fallbackHeight: maxExtent * 1.5,
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Container(
              height: kToolbarHeight,
              color: Colors.deepPurple.withAlpha(100),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text('Title'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => expandedHeight;

  @override
  double get minExtent => kToolbarHeight;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(covariant AppSliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) => oldDelegate.expandedHeight != expandedHeight;
}
```

And use

```dart
slivers: [
  SliverPersistentHeader(
    pinned: true,
    delegate: AppSliverPersistentHeaderDelegate(expandedHeight: 200),
  ),
```

Initial look

[image]

And on scroll

[image]